# Pandas error when using if-else to create new column: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas and am trying to create a new column using a Python if-else statement (aka ternary condition operator) in order to avoid division by zero.

For example below, I want to create a new column C by dividing A/B. I want to use the if-else statement to avoid dividing by 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df.head()
#    A  B
# 0  1  3
# 1  1  2
# 2  0  0
# 3  2  1
# 4  4  2

df['C'] = (df.A / df.B) if df.B > 0.0 else 0.0
```

However, I am getting an error from the last line:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I searched on StackOverflow and found other posts about this error, but none of them involved this type of if-else statement. Some posts include:

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

[The truth value of a Series is ambiguous in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811610/the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-in-dataframe)

[Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493948/error-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-python-pandas)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "but none of them involved this type of if-else statement" - this code actually shows a conditional *expression*, not a statement; but it fails for the same reason that an `if` statement does, which is the same reason that `and` and `or` do - all of which is quite thoroughly covered in the canonical now, if it wasn't in 2018.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`df.B > 0` results in a Series, e.g.:

```
0      True  # 4 > 0 => True
1      True  # 2 > 0 => True
2      True  # ...
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False  # 0 is not > 0 => False
9     False  # 0 is not > 0 => False
...
```

Multiple values are returned which results in ambiguity (some are True while others are False).

One solution is to use `np.where`:

```
sentinel = np.nan  # Or 0 if you must...
df = df.assign(C=np.where(df['B'] != 0, df['A'] / df['B'], sentinel))
>>> df
   A  B    C
0  2  4  0.5
1  0  2  0.0
2  1  2  0.5
3  4  4  1.0
4  1  1  1.0
5  4  4  1.0
6  2  4  0.5
7  1  2  0.5
8  4  0  NaN  # NaN is assigned in cases where the value in Column `B` is zero.
9  1  0  NaN
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not even know `np.where()` existed or why it would be needed here.

Comment: And if you don't want to import numpy just for `where`, you can use pandas's `.np` accessor:  `pd.np.where(...`

Comment: @robroc To be clear, one implicitly imports numpy when importing pandas, so there is no difference in memory or performance.  The only difference would be the alias, `np` vs `pd.np`.  You can confirm for yourself via: `import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd`

`id(pd.np) == id(np)` which results in `True`

Answer (score 15):

What about doing

```
>>> df['C'] = np.where(df.B>0., df.A/df.B, 0.)
```

which reads as :

> where `df.B` is strictly positive, return `df.A/df.B`, otherwise return `0.`

Comment: Thank you. I think `np.where()` should be renamed to be: `np.if_then_else(if, then, else)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @vaishnav proposal above on iterating over the dataframe here is a working proposal:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.B > 0:
        df.loc[index, 'C'] = row.A / row.B
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'C'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B         C
0  3  4  0.750000
1  0  4  0.000000
2  4  3  1.333333
3  2  1  2.000000
4  1  0  0.000000
5  0  2  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C']=df.A.div(df.B.mask(df.B.lt(0),0)).fillna(0)
df
Out[89]: 
   A  B         C
0  1  3  0.333333
1  1  2  0.500000
2  0  0  0.000000
3  2  1  2.000000
4  4  2  2.000000
```

With apply lambda

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x : x['A']/x['B'] if x['B']>0 else 0,1)
df
Out[93]: 
   A  B         C
0  1  3  0.333333
1  1  2  0.500000
2  0  0  0.000000
3  2  1  2.000000
4  4  2  2.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just open a  for loop.

```
for i,j in df['a'],df['b']:
    if j>0:
        df['c']=i/j
    else:
        df['c']=0.0
```

Comment: You should test your code before you post it.  This raises an ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).  I will post a separate answer for readability following your approach iterating over the df.