# Loop return error that the true value of the series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I am trying to tell pandas that:

If Report No. is below 30, he needs to create a new variable that is equal to

> df_bei_index[col]*0.05 + df_bei_index['PDI_Average']*0.95.

If Report No. is higher or equal to 30, he needs to create a new variable that is equal to

> df_bei_index[col]

I wrote the following code:

```
for col in col_list:
    if df_bei_index['Report No'] <= 29:
        df_bei_index[col+'_final'] = df_bei_index[col]*0.05 + df_bei_index['PDI_Average']*0.95
    else:
        df_bei_index[col+'_final'] = df_bei_index[col]
```

But I get this error

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        10 
>        11 for col in col_list:
>   ---> 12     if df_bei_index['Report No'] <= 29:
>        13         df_bei_index[col+'_final'] = df_bei_index[col]*0.05 + df_bei_index['PDI_Average']*0.95
>        14     else:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
>   **nonzero**(self)    1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1575                          "Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>   -> 1576                          .format(self.**class**.**name**))    1577     1578     **bool** = **nonzero**
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer:
[Python Use if function: ValueError:Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828894/python-use-if-function-valueerrortruth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-e)

You may want to use np.where:

```
for col in col_list:
        df_bei_index[col+'_final'] = np.where(df_bei_index['Report No'] <=29, df_bei_index[col]*0.05 + df_bei_index['PDI_Average']*0.95, df_bei_index[col])
```

I am assuming you are excluding your 'Country' column from the 'col_list' list

Answer (score 0):

An expression like `df_bei_index['Report No'] <= 29` has type `Series(bool)`, so you cannot use it in an if statement, but you can use it as an index in `.loc` for your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': list(range(20)), 'b': list(range(6,26))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

condition1 = df.a <= 10
condition2 = df.a > 10
df.loc[condition1, 'a_1'] = df.loc[condition1]['a'] * 2
df.loc[condition2, 'a_1'] = df.loc[condition2]['a'] * 5
```