# Creating a variable conditional to the value of another variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate variable which is value depend on the value of another variable. My dataset is `urban_classification` and I am trying to create the variable `URBRUR` based on the value of the variable `prc_urbain`. This is my code:

```
if urban_classification.prc_urbain>0.5 :
    urban_classification['URBRUR'] = "urban"
else:
    urban_classification['URBRUR'] = "rural"
```

and I get this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-a94aadb86c32>", line 31, in <module>
    if urban_classification.prc_urbain>0.5 :
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can you indicate me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas error when using if-else to create new column: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123368/pandas-error-when-using-if-else-to-create-new-column-the-truth-value-of-a-serie)

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

comes from

```
if urban_classification.prc_urbain>0.5 :
```

because `urban_classification.prc_urbain` is a pd.Series, hence  `urban_classification.prc_urbain>0.5` is also a pd.Series made of True/False values, and python is not able to determine if this list of booleans should evaluate to True or not.

To achieve what you want, you can use [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
urban_classification["URBRUR"] = pd.cut(urban_classification.prc_urbain, [0, 0.5, 1], labels=["rural", "urban], include_lowest=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd                                                     
s = pd.Series([0, 0.1, 0.45, 0.6, 0.8, 1])                              
pd.cut(s, [0, 0.5, 1], labels=("rural", "urban"), include_lowest=True)                       


0    rural
1    rural
2    rural
3    urban
4    urban
5    urban
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `urban_classification.prc_urbain` is not a number you can directly compare to `0.5`, but a `pandas.Series` object (basically a one-dimensional array).

The error you see is asking you to be more specific: do you want all the values in the array to be `>0.5`, any specific one of them, etc...

If you believe the array is composed by just one element, you only need to append `[0]` to the Series object, e.g.:

```py
if urban_classification.prc_urbain[0] > 0.5:
    urban_classification['URBRUR'] = "urban"
else:
    urban_classification['URBRUR'] = "rural"
```