# Value error while comparing a pandas series with integer value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data-frame of the format

[image: data]

where I apply a conditional operator on a series :

```
list1=[]
if  (fi['datedelta'] <10): list1.append(fi['TC'])
```

I get the value error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I found out a few resources addressing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123368/pandas-error-when-using-if-else-to-create-new-column-the-truth-value-of-a-serie/48123413)
After which , I tried :

```
if(np.where(fi['datedelta'] <= 10 & fi['datedelta'] > 0)):list1.append(fi['TC'])
```

but I am getting the same error.

Comment: The use of the ":" here is wrong, what do you want to achieve? You can probably get there by using `.loc[...]`. Can you give the a bit more context, and post the sample data not as picture but as text that can be copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to loop through the Dataframe, try this:

```
list1=[]
for i in range(fi.shape[0]):
    if (fi['datedelta'][i] <10):
        list1.append(fi['TC'][i])
```

#### More efficient method -

```
list1 = list(fi.loc[fi.datedelta<10, 'TC'])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :) could you let me know why ```np.where``` was not working

Comment: fi['datedelta'] <= 10  will return a pandas series containing True and False Boolean values and you cannot apply '&' operator on two pandas series objects

Try printing just 'fi['datedelta'] <= 10' you will understand better