# I am getting Value Error when using if else to manipulate dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I have written and df is dataframe.
I am using python3 and I am new to pandas and I have tried bitwise operator as well as keywords and or

```
if((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-0.5) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=0.5)):

    df['Trend']="Slight or No Change"

elif((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=0.5) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=1)):

    df['Trend']="Slight Positive"

elif((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-1) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=-0.5)):

    df['Trend']="Slight Negative"

elif((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=1) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=3)):

    df['Trend']="Positive"

elif((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-3) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=-1)):

    df['Trend']="Negative"

elif((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=3) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=7)):

    df['Trend']='Among top gainers'
```

else:

```
    df['Trend']="Bear drop"
}
```

> **This is the error I am getting
>
> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>  I have used both and as well as | but it is working.
> Can anyone help me out?
> ​**
> ```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas error when using if-else to create new column: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123368/pandas-error-when-using-if-else-to-create-new-column-the-truth-value-of-a-serie)

Answer (score 0):

BAM, `np.where()`, which is also vectorized and high-performing.

```
df['Trend'] = ''
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-0.5) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=0.5), "Slight or No Change", df['Trend'])
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=0.5) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=1), "Slight Positive", df['Trend'])
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-1) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=-0.5), "Slight Negative", df['Trend'])
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=1) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=3), "Positive", df['Trend'])
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=-3) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=-1), "Negative", df['Trend'])
df['Trend'] = np.where((df['Day_Perc_Change']>=3) & (df['Day_Perc_Change']<=7), "Among top gainers", df['Trend'])
```